# Getting missing buildings from OpenStreetMap (OSM) file into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, vector-layer

I am trying to build a map with the footprints of the buildings using QGIS. So far, it was straightforward to import OSM file generated by OpenStreetMap, but unfortunately, the map is not complete. There are only a few buildings that are available, as you can see in the image below:

[image]

So far I couldn't find any vector map that would show those buildings. I saw in a previous post that there exist such a map on [this website](http://geoportal.ancpi.ro/geoportal/viewer/index.html) (see image extract in the picture below).

[image]

The problem is that the map was built in Flash and I cannot extract it as vector data. I can see however that the map was built in ArcGIS and I was wondering if there is any way to get such a map for QGIS. I have tried importing and *shp from [here](https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/romania.html), but it is the same as in the first picture. My knowledge ended there, and I have realized that I don't even know how to search for such a vector map with all the buildings.

Can anyone help me with this or guide me on how/where to search for such a map?

Comment: OpenStreetMap (OSM) is a project of "**Volunteered** Geographic System". Therefore, you can not get those buildings from OSM until any volunteer adds them to OSM.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So you are saying that that ArcGIS map is a commercial one and one would need to purchase it?

Answer (score 3):

As @Kadir Şahbaz commented, if you want to use data from OpenStreetMap, then you can download only what has been already added.

Your screenshot is taken from the Romanian Geoportal made by [ANCPI](http://www.ancpi.ro/), which is indeed based on commercial Esri software. At this stage, the application does not allow for data download, even if you have an Esri ArcGIS license.

The only data you can download is from the Geoportal's [webpage](http://geoportal.ancpi.ro/geoportal/catalog/main/home.page), though only current administrative boundaries are available (*you will need an account for the download button to appear*).

Some Romanian cities and towns have their own Web Feature Services which you can use (in the past, some could be found using [GeoSeer](https://www.geoseer.net/) or [Spatineo](http://directory.spatineo.com/)), but I don't think Rădăuți is among them. If you need specific building data for that town, I would suggest contacting the planning department of the Mayor's Office, or in the worst case, digitise them yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications,  Cezar.  Will check Geoseer and Spantineo and see how it goes. I have tried doing it by myself using QGIS and it's a hell of a job to get those footprints.